# Adding Images to GridView

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store

I am trying to add Images to a GridView, but the images never actually show.
Instead, I'm just display the class name in a Thumbnail looking layout.

Here is the code that I have been tweaking

```
public async void setImage(string url) {

    Byte[] imageBytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
    var randomAccessStream = new MemoryRandomAccessStream(stream);

    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    await image.SetSourceAsync(randomAccessStream);

    imagesGrid.Items.Add(image);           
}
```

Thanks for the help. I ended up with the following block that works.

```
public void setImage(string url) {
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));

    imagesGrid.Items.Add(img);           
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you're adding `BitmapImage`s to your visual tree.  `BitmapImage`s are not visual elements.  What you need to do is create an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR242752) and set the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx) property to the URI of your image file.  There are a number of examples of this in xaml and also code on my blog [here](http://windows8applicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2012/09/loading-resources.html).

I haven't tested this but it should be something like this:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
imagesGrid.Items.Add(img);
```